# Changing text entered by user into UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Just playing around with some code for practice more than anything. I'm writing an app where users enter text into a UITextView, presses a button and every word entered is changed to a single word, defined by the program, keeping the punctuation intact.

How would this be achieved? I initially thought of counting the words and simply replacing them but that didn't work as the punctuation disappears.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
NSString *inputString = @"Replace all the words! Will you?";
NSString *substitutionString = @"bla";
NSMutableString *outputString = [inputString mutableCopy];

[outputString enumerateSubstringsInRange:(NSRange){0, [outputString length]} options:NSStringEnumerationByWords usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
    [outputString replaceOccurrencesOfString:substring withString:substitutionString options:0 range:substringRange];
}];

NSLog(@"%@", outputString);
```

Comment: Much better! I feel stupid now... :)

Comment: Certainly pointed me in the right direction and definitely a much easier solution than what I was trying to do! Thank you sir.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is cell reusability issue, try creating cell identifier like this. It will work.

```
NSString *identifier =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_%d",indexPath.row,indexPath.section];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }
```

If you are using custom cell, cell creation code will be changed accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Shahab but I'm not using a tableview, only UITextView.